# Using and displaying a JLabel from a differnet class

Tags: java, swing

I am a beginner java programmer. I have two classes both in     package1. I am trying to use a     JLabel from another class in     Main , here are the two pieces of code:

```
package package1;
import package1.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.*;

public class Main extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
//Event Text
    protected static JLabel eventText;
    public void event1() {
    eventText = event1.event1EventText;
   }
   private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Stack Overflow");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Main newContentPane = new Main();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true);
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);
        frame.setSize(1300, 700);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();  
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My second file just makes a JLabel.

```
package package1;

import javax.swing.*;

public class event1 extends JPanel {
    protected static JLabel event1EventText;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        event1EventText = new JLabel();
        event1EventText.setText("Some text");
    }
}
```

I need to use     event1EventText in     Main . I do not get any error when I run the code but     eventText never displays. I just get a empty window.

Comment: main() in event1 is never executed so the label is never created.

Comment: You may also want to look at The Swing Tutorial (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html). The way you are doing it is not good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little vague and the solution might differ based on more context, however, generally, if you have components in another component, you don't want to allow direct access to them, as it's too easy for other parts your program to do things to them that they really shouldn't be doing.

Instead, one approach is to provide setters and getters to change the state of the label indirectly, for example...

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test100 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test100();
    }

    public Test100() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                TestPane pane = new TestPane();
                pane.setLabelText("Look, I'm a label on another panel");

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(pane);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JLabel label;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            label = new JLabel();
            add(label);
        }

        public void setLabelText(String text) {
            label.setText(text);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

oh  i think the problem is that you don not put the eventText in class Main to the frame in the method createAndShowGUI.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this solution :-

package package1;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.*;

public class Main extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
//Event Text
    protected static JLabel eventText;
    public static void event1() {
    eventText = event1.createLabel();
   }
   private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Stack Overflow");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        event1();
        Main newContentPane = new Main();
        newContentPane.add(eventText);
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true);
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);
        frame.setSize(1300, 700);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();  
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}


package package1;

import javax.swing.*;

public class event1 extends JPanel {
    protected static JLabel event1EventText;
    protected static JLabel createLabel(){
         event1EventText = new JLabel();
         event1EventText.setText("Some text");
         return event1EventText;
    }
}
```

Comment: `eventText` should be `static`, the moemnt you create another instance of `Main`, it'll be removed from it's current container. If you want to use the label, you should actually add the panel to the frame. Generally it's bad practice to directly reference components from other components in this way, as it's too easy for people to do stupid things with them....

Comment: *"eventText should be static"* - should be "shouldn't" - I'm giving up on typing :P

Comment: eventText should not be static. In memory only one copy of static components is maintained per class. So accessing static components from multiple objects would create inconsistency.